# What regulator do I need for 500 gallon tank?

Tags: gas, propane, regulator

Just moved into a new house, the previous owner had a 500-gallon propane tank buried in the backyard. A gas contractor stopped by and said the tank is in full working order, however he doesn't do installation. The tank at this point is not connected to anything. It was originally connected to a pool water heater, but the original owner said he replaced the heater to electric. The pictures attached I found online, but it is the same make and model, the only difference is the serial number.

I will be running an underground polyethylene line for about 80-100 feet. **What size regulator do I need?**

I'm planning on using a [first stage regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MT7NG0X) (like this one), then run the line and use a [second stage regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N20XKTC) and finally connect [my appliance which already has a built in regulator](https://www.thermador.com/us/products-list/cooktops-rangetops/rangetops/PCG366W#/Tabs=section-technicalspecs/Togglebox=-1202905702/Togglebox=-1202905708/Togglebox=-1998997503/Togglebox=-582378998/Togglebox=-658916038/Togglebox=-697829455/Togglebox=-836809633/Togglebox=-960854172/Togglebox=1533709153/Togglebox=439618541/Togglebox=-230088015/).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regulators are not based on the tank size but the load you will be serving. What will you be running? Furnace, stove, gas log, BBQ, water heater , clothes dryer. This information and the BTU’s for each will be needed to size the regulator.

Comment: Hi @EdBeal thanks for your reply. For now only the stove (with 6 18,000 BTU burners) and in a few months we're installing a 400k BTU Pentair Pool Heater.

Comment: So you need a primary regulator to take the pressure down to 8-10 psi then the secondary to be large enough to handle at least 500k btu  (I would go larger) Amazon had a 1400k second stage 2” water column for under 60$ You rarely have all the burners on at the same time but in a year or 2 you may want to upgrade a furnace so if the cost difference is none or minimal I go larger with the regs and upsize the pipe